# Custom CSS classes for Data Labels in Donut Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, class, highcharts

I'm working on this donut chart

I was wondering if it's possible to assign a different custom CSS class to each data label in order to style each one with a different icon and to correct the positioning issues.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it as the correct one by clicking the outline of a checkmark (when you can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (thanx to fcodebue)!
If anyone can find this useful...
Here's the complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fcodebue/qkJtk/8/

Starting from the highcharts donut oie demo -to assign a custom class from the array to each label modify the the formatter like this:

```
//assign classes from array
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<div class="boheti2 '+classes2[this.point.x]+'">'+'<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b></div>'  : null;
```

where `boheti2` is a class for the general styling for external labels, and `classes2` is the name of the classes array

Comment: your link is not working any more.  Can you add in a working fiddle?